# NSDictionary stringForKey: and Casting [NSNull null] to NSString*

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was recently told casting `[NSNull null]` to `(NSString*)` was "terrible".

However, `-[NSDictionary stringForKey:]` method will return `[NSNull null]` if the key is not in the dictionary, and if I don't do the cast the compiler yells at me.

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

My mistake... and I think I might be beginning to see the problem...

As everyone has pointed out, there is no stringForKey: method on NSDictionary, and yes, I was thinking about the user defaults when I asked the question... so I went back and looked at what I was doing... here it is:

```
NSString * someValue = (NSString*)[myDictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
if (someValue == (NSString*)[NSNull null]) ...
```

if I don't do the cast in this case, I get the following error:

```
warning: comparison of distinct Objective-C types 'struct NSNull *' and 'struct NSString *' lacks a cast
```

Casting the value "solves" the problem, and I'd rather not write 10 lines where one will do...

Is this bad? Where will I run into problems?

ALSO:

The dictionaries are coming from a JSON library... and NULLs are valid values in this case, so perhaps it's not that NSDictionary returns them if the key is missing, but rather that the key is, in fact, there, and the value is actually null.

Comment: I just checked the docs, and `NSDictionary` doesn't appear to *have* a `stringForKey:` method.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSDictionary` does not return instances of `NSNull` unless you or some other source put them there. As well, `NSDictionary` does not respond to `-stringForKey:`. Are you perhaps thinking of `NSUserDefaults`?

If you have an instance of `NSDictionary` and all you want to do is get a string from it, you could try something like the following code.

```
NSString *MyGetString(NSDictionary *dict, id key, NSString *fallback) {
    id result = [dict objectForKey: key];

    if (!result)
        result = fallback;
    else if (![result isKindOfClass: [NSString class]])
        result = [result description];

    return result;
}
```

Pass a fallback string as `fallback`--the function will use that if no object is associated with the key `key`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question to clarify... and I think your answer is great... but I'm still curious if there is anything inherently "bad" about the solution I have already (for my own edification).

Comment: If you mean casting `NSNull` to `NSString`, it's awful, because it's like calling a dog a fish. Yes, they're both in the same hierarchy (subclasses of `NSObject` vs. species in *Chordata*) but they're very different things. --- If instead you mean *comparing* two objects of different types (as in your updated question), you can instead cast both to `id`, which they both are (so it's a safe comparison.) e.g. `(id)someValue == (id)[NSNull null]` would be valid. Better still would be to store the dictionary in an `id` to begin with, and only do the cast to `NSString` *after* you check the type.

Comment: Thanks!! I added a category for NSDictionary that does what you suggest, and still keeps everything simple for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: I created a category based on Jonathan's code. Thank you! https://github.com/tiemevanveen/NSDictionary-StringForKey

Comment: Some minor important details here - the comparison to [NSNull null] using '==' operation will ONLY work for [NSNull null] because it is a singleton, and all NSNulls are actually the very same shared instance. When you do not KNOW in advance the type of object you'll get as value from a Dictionary, better use 'id' to signify that, and also if you must compare it to some specific instance of specific class - first make sure the class makes sense, and then use isEqual: instead of '=='

Answer (score 7):

as Jonathan's code shows, it's better if you use `isKindOfClass:` method. It'll protect you even if you change your method of retrieving the object, etc. and is a more accurate check.

Also remember that `[someValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` returns `YES` only when `someValue` is not `nil` AND it's an `NSString` which means it's also enough for testing `nil` values.

Answer (score 6):

The cast is "bad" because `NSNull` *is not* an `NSString`. Casting does not change the actual type of the object pointed to, it only changes the compiler's, um, *attitude* to it.

In the very particular case shown, where the *only* thing you're going to do with the object is a direct test for pointer equality, your approach will work, but it's a source of potential future errors. This sort of hacky cast to silence compiler warnings makes one uneasy to look at and should be avoided if there's a better way.

The real problem, of course, is the *previous* cast, where the `NSObject*` from `objectForKey:` is cast straight to an `NSString*` with no questions asked. At present you can get away with it because you think you're guaranteed to get only strings or `NSNull`, but what happens if the JSON library changes or just fails to honour that contract? You'd really be better off doing something like:

```
NSObject* someValue = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"key"];
NSString* someStr = nil;
if (someValue == [NSNull null])
   ...
else if ([someValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   someStr = (NSString*) someValue;
....
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't give multiple people credit for an answer, so I had to give it to Jonathan for a similar (and earlier) answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this category extension to wrap this logic up.
it's on github

*NSDictionary+Verified.h*:

```
//  NSDictionary+Verified.h
//
//  Created by alexruperez on 08/05/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 alexruperez. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (Verified)

- (id)verifiedObjectForKey:(id)aKey;

@end
```

*NSDictionary+Verified.m*:

```
NSDictionary+Verified.m

#import "NSDictionary+Verified.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Verified)

- (id)verifiedObjectForKey:(id)aKey
{
    if ([self objectForKey:aKey] && ![[self objectForKey:aKey] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) return [self objectForKey:aKey];
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a very good solution. Specially I got this notorious NSNull bug when my backend returns JSON with null object, some fields are empty - no problem, but if some objects are set null, then JSON serialization creates NSNull for those values in the parsed dictionary.

Comment: What's 'notorious' about [NSNull null] ? it's a great way to say "unknown value for this specific key". Foundation collections CAN NOT hold a 'nil' reference. The only viable solution is to have an object instance that signifies 'nil' or 'none' or 'unknown'.   Many scenarios call for this, not just UserDefaults.  For instance NSDictionary has a great method:
``- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys;`` Which will provide NSNull for keys in your 'key's array not in the receiver NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

A good test for NULL checking, especially when testing parsed results from network APIs (JSON especially) is the `isEqual:` method. I test for both existence, and for a usable value using...

```
NSString *someValue = [response objectForKey:MyAPIKeySomeValue];
if (!!someValue && ![someValue isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
    // optionally test for class type
    // use someValue
}
else {
    // error out for required values; skip for optional values
}
```

On a more general note, if you're expecting JSON in a specific format, and the API is not meeting that requirement, you could consider that a candidate for wrapping in a `@try/@catch`. You can then handle the abnormal/illegal response format, and eliminate hard crashes for invalid data formats.

If the format is loosely defined, you could allow your parsing routines to fail more gracefully by constructing a meaningful `NSError`.

Comment: that's great .but why not use   "if (someValue ..)"  instead of double inversion on somevalue variable  ?